# How to install java 8 using dockerfile in python:3.8-slim-buster base image

Tags: java, python, docker, centos, dockerfile

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
RUN python --version
RUN apt-get install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --default-timeout=100 pyspark
```

I want to install java 8 and set JAVA_HOME variables. But when I am trying to build above image I am getting below error:

```
E: Unable to locate package java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel'
```

This is my first attempt in creating a docker image. Please suggest what is wrong with above Dockerfile. I am working on centos7.

Comment: Try updating the packages list before trying to install the packages i.e. `apt-get update && apt-get install -y ...`.

Comment: Why do you need two different language runtimes in the same image?  Can you build a second image `FROM openjdk:8` and run the Java component in a second container?

Comment: @DavidMaze My application uses pyspark which needs both java and python.

Comment: @user0204 is your issue resolved? can you tell what worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is that you can build your Dockerfile based on `FROM ubuntu:20.04` where Python 3.8 is set as default ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232812/whats-the-default-python-version-in-ubuntu-20-04)). Then, install `java` and `pip` later.

> FROM ubuntu:20.04
>
> ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
>
> RUN apt-get update -y \ 
> && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \ 
> && add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa \ 
> && apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y \ 
> && apt-get install python3-pip -y \ 
> && export JAVA_HOME \ 
> && apt-get clean \ 
> && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Comment: hope this would be helpful!

Comment: does this work for you @user0204